# How to Send data from from one components flat-list to another component in react native

Tags: react-native

Categories.js

```
 <FlatList
            data={categorylist}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.tc_id}
            vertical
            numColumns={4}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
              return (
                <Pressable onPress={subcat}>
                <View style={styles.catLayout}>
                  <View style={styles.imageLayout}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.image}
                     />
                  </View>

                  <Text style={styles.productname}>
                    {item.name != null ? item.name : ""}
                  </Text>
                  <Text>{item.uuid}</Text>
                </View>
                </Pressable>
                );
            }}
          />
```

I am getting data from categorylist array , i am displaying a bunch of items of categories here , i want show different sub-categories depending on each items "uuid".
I want to send the {item.uuid} to subcategories screen and reuse it in there.

Answer (score 0):

As you are displaying the data on the view using flatlist you have onPress after clicking on any item you just need to send the data

**Screen (A)**

```
  <FlatList
        data={categorylist}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.tc_id}
        vertical
        numColumns={4}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <Pressable onPress={() => navigation.navigate('subcategories',{uuid:item.uuid}) }>
            <View style={styles.catLayout}>
              <View style={styles.imageLayout}>
                <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.image}
                 />
              </View>

              <Text style={styles.productname}>
                {item.name != null ? item.name : ""}
              </Text>
              <Text>{item.uuid}</Text>
            </View>
            </Pressable>
            );
        }}
      />
```

**Screen (B)**

you can get it like this

**class component**

```
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       uuID: this.props.navigation.state.params.uuid,
     }
 }
```

**functional component**

```
const Subcategory = (props) => {
const [uUID, setuUID] = useState(props.route.params.uuid);
```

Comment: constructor is my subcategories component right???

Comment: it's a functional component i am using can't use constructor

Comment: yes I have given for both you can check it